# App.config files in XBAP

Tags: publishing, xbap

I'm developing an XBAP application with FullTrust. I have an App.config file which is part of the XBAP application. I use it to read some values from the AppSettings section.

The scenario is, I publish my application once to IIS with some values in the App.config file. Now, if I need to update some values in the App.config file how can I do that without having to re-publish my application to IIS.

Thanks,
Jithu

Answer (score 3):

Please check

[Deploy XBAP Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834067/deploy-xbap-application)

http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2009/11/06/new-wpf-features-full-trust-xbap-deployment.aspx

You need to resign you manifest file with your pfx certifcate.

OR wait until

http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2009/11/06/new-wpf-features-full-trust-xbap-deployment.aspx